# Can online quantum random number generators be used in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, random

I want to avoid repetitions as much as possible. I've run the same Matlab program that uses "random" numbers multiple times and gotten exactly the same results. I learned that I should put the command `shuffle` at the beginning, and then the program will replace the default seed with a new one, based on the time on the clock. But the sequence of outputs from the pseudo-random number generator will 
still contain a pattern.

I recently learned about a quantum box random number generator ([this](http://www.idquantique.com/random-number-generation/quantis-ais-31/) or something like it), and in the process of looking it up online I found a couple web servers that deliver random numbers that are continuously generated by quantum mechanical means: [ANU Photonics](http://photonics.anu.edu.au/qoptics/Research/qrng.php) and [ANU QRNG](http://qrng.anu.edu.au/).

To buy a quantum box looks pretty hard to afford, so how might I integrate one of the online servers into Matlab?

Comment: (1) It really sounds that you lack the basics or PRNGS and your *patterns* are due to wrong usage. (2) It's much easier to do something bad (scientifically) with *true random numbers* compared to the well-known PRNGS. (3) I can't imagine many use-cases (actually zero at the moment) where i would feel the need to use a service like that. (4) Why is there a question + answer posted at the same time? (5) **While you might use these sources somehow, i strongly recommend telling us more about the use-case and the !exact! problems obtained with PRNGS as i feel you are on the wrong path!**

Comment: I'm studying information theory, where it is very significant that the [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) of a series of random numbers is no greater than that of the random number generator. Thus, while `mod((key+pi)^5)` may appear to generate random numbers, it is actually very simple. And though standard PRNGs are certainly more complex than that, it's important in my project to not acquire any unnecessary errors in my estimates of Kolmogorov complexities.

Comment: The question is then how you estimate these complexities. From a practical viewpoint, no non-bad PRNG output will ever be possible to compress (with current algorithms like LZW/PPMZ...) which gives some approximative bounds here. Then it's also important what kind of random-numbers you need and how these are produced in the hardware-based setting. That's not my expertise, but randomness-extraction has it's own complex theory (and everything based on entropy-estimation is kind of scary from a theoretical viewpoint).

Comment: While it's now clear to me, that you know something about randomness, i still am wondering what kind of patterns you did observe and how you did that. Breaking a PRNG is not that easy i would think. You did not provide much information and maybe the problems are solely due to bad initialization (which is a problem with at least with MersenneTwister).

Comment: I want to be secure from the means by which I estimate the Kolmogorov complexity of data measuring that value to be smaller than it actually is on the basis of the patterns it "notices" in the data being patterns that came from what was supposed to be random actually coming from an algorithm. I am not focusing at all on finding the patterns myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On http://qrng.anu.edu.au, click the "download" link in the text, and it takes you to a [FAQ page](http://qrng.anu.edu.au/FAQ.php#api) where it tells what to download to use the random number generator in different ways. The last on the list is Matlab, for which it gives a link to directly download some code to access the random numbers and a link to Matlab Central to download the JSON Parser which is necessary for it to work.

The code is very simple, and as a script only displays the values it fetches, but can easily be turned into a function. I unzipped the contents of parse_json.zip into C:/Program Files/MATLAB/[version]/toolbox/JSONparser, a new folder in the Toolboxes, navigated to the Toolboxes in the Current Folder in Matlab, right clicked JSONparser, and clicked Add to Path.

Read the comments on the Matlab Central page for JSON Parser to get an idea of the limits of how many random numbers you can pull down at a time.

The random numbers are 16-bit non-negative integers; to create a random integer with more bits, say, 32 bits, I'd recommend taking two of these integers, multiplying one by 2^16, and adding them. If you want a number between 0 and 1, divide the sum by 2^32.